# how to convert a cloudformation template to a terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform-provider-aws

I have found questions to convert terraform to cloudformation , but wondering if there is one for this . I am creating a REST api , with api gateway and lambda ( code below) . the stack is working with cloudformation, trying to convert this to terraform. I have version (AWS::Lambda::Version) and asynconfig (AWS::Lambda::EventInvokeConfig) set up for my lambda , but don't see anything similar in terraform.

```
lambdaFunc 
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    FunctionName: something
    ...
  version:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Ref: lambdaFunc
  asyncconfig:
     Type: AWS::Lambda::EventInvokeConfig
     Properties:
       FunctionName:
         Ref: lambdaFunc
       MaximumRetryAttemps: 0
       Qualifier: $LATEST
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/humanmade/cf-to-tf or something similar?

Comment: Best way is to do it manually.

Comment: @marcin : thanks - does terraform support version for lambda ,similar to cfn.